# SQL changing DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD in two existing columns

Tags: sql, ssms

I have two columns in one table both containing a mix of DD-MM-YYYY and YYYY-MM-DD formatting.
The cells with the YYYY-MM-DD are correct, but I want to update the DD-MM-YYYY cells to the same format. What query do I use?

Can't get it to work.

Comment: What DBMS? Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Since the year is moving from the beginning to the end and the year has a different number of characters, you could use `LIKE` in your `WHERE` clause with wildcard characters to match a specific format. In T-SQL to find all the ones with the incorrect format it would look like `WHERE LIKE '__-__-____'`

Comment: Save yourself from these issues by using the right datatype for your data, in this case `DATE`

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format; the format is determined by your presentation layer. Presumably you have (foolishly) stored your date (and time) data in a string based data type, so what you actually need to be asking is how you change the **displayed** format of the date in your presentation layer.

Comment: @Jesse Yes, Microsoft SQL Server